# Android reading button background from drawable folder

Tags: android

I have set up my button in Android. It has background image, and of course I have thought about [Multiple Screen Size](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). I web I have red that I need 3 layout folders  for mobile phones:

```
1)layout-small
2)layout-normal
3)layout-large
```

And I have learnded that I need to make diffrent button images to button background. I mean size of picture. If I am true then:

```
1)layout-small reads images from drawable-ldpi
2)layout-normal reads images from drawable-mdpi
3)layout-large reads images from drawable-hdpi
```

But I think I am not because I started my app from large phones and my button is very small. I think in my app layout-large reads from drawable-ldpi. Can someone explain me more about Multiple Screen Size.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish screen size (small, normal, large) from screen density (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi). Just because a phone has a large screen size does not mean it has hdpi (or xhdpi) density.
If you really have problems with that, you can create folders with different images for specific screen sizes AND resolutions, ie. you can have folders

```
res/layout-large    
res/layout-large-xhdpi    
res/layout-large-hdpi
```

and so on.